# package-lock.json is being overwritten after `npm i --production` but to lockfileVersion 1, when using Node 18

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

In our Jenkins system, we run `npm install --production` for a bunch of folders that contain package.json and package-lock.json files.

I have a lock file, on lockfileVersion 3 (created with Node 18, NPM v9) which is getting overwritten in Jenkins to lockfileVersion 1, despite Jenkins also using Node 18 and NPM v9.

The file is pulled from git correctly, but once the job starts running the `npm i` commands, the file is overwritten. How is it doing this, and why? How is it creating a v1 lockfileVersion?